# How to the set path in an image tag which ia made dynamically by dom in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am facing a problem which is that I have a image tag which I made dynamically but when I assign the path by SRC attribute it is not working. How  can I get the solution please? My code is following:

```
function GetAllProduct() {
    $("#AllProductArea").empty();
    var Count = 0;

    $.getJSON("/api/tblProducts/AllProduct", function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            var pic1Path = '~/ProductsImages/' + val.PrdPic1;
            alert(pic1Path + " PP");
            $('<option>Smlr' + val.PrdName + '</option>').appendTo("#LstPrdSimlarTo");


            $('<div id="btnAreaPrd" class="btnArea"><span id=Product' + Count + ' class="IdHed">' + val.ProductId + '</span><input type="button" id=' + Count + ' value="Get Details " class="btnSaveChanges"><span class="addheddings">Quantity  </span><span class="addheddings">' + val.Quantity + '</span><span id=' + Count + ' class="UpadteHed">Upadate</span><span id=' + Count + ' class="DelHed">Delete</span></div><table id="tblProducts" class="tblLayout"><tr><td><img id=Img' + Count + ' Class="imgOrder"></td><td>  <span id="orderName" class="orderSubHed">' + val.PrdName + '</span></td><td><span id="orderPrice" class="orderSubHed">' + val.PrdDisPrice + '</span></td><td><span id="orderStatus" class="orderSubHed">' + val.StockStatus + '</span></td></tr></table><br><br>').appendTo("#AllProductArea");
            alert(Count + " countValue");
            alert('#Img' + Count);
            $('#Img' + Count).attr('src', pic1Path);

            Count = Count + 1;

        });
    });
```

Here my pic path is in pic1Path variable. Please help me.

Comment: Where is `Count` declared?

Comment: Sorry sir i write half code now it's  updated

Comment: @AkshayTomar do you get any error?

Comment: @AkshayTomar when you call this function "GetAllProduct()" ? In document.ready or else?

Comment: “Not working” is not a proper problem description. Please go read [ask] first of all now. And then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: `pic1Path` is incorrect.  You can't use `~` in client side script.  You must change that to a relative path to the page that is running the script.

Comment: @KiranShahi no mam i don't get any error

Comment: @ManishVadher yes sir i am calling it in the document.ready

Comment: @Archer sir how to change it on relative path ?

Comment: @Archer sir thanks you got the real reason of it thanks i am facing this problem approx 2 days

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the `src` attribute.

```js
$("#Img" + Count).attr('src', pic1Path);
```

Answer (score -1):

Verify id of `<img>` tag that must match where you are setting `$("#Img" + Count).attr('src', pic1Path);`.

Comment: It's matching sir

Comment: console.log(pic1Path) and check result

Comment: where to write Sir ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. You have to refresh Image Source if it is in cache.

```
pic1Path=pic1Path+"?"+CreateGuid();
$("#Img" + Count).attr('src', pic1Path);
```

Create separate function outside Document.Ready

```
 function CreateGuid() {  
       function _p8(s) {  
          var p = (Math.random().toString(16)+"000000000").substr(2,8);  
          return s ? "-" + p.substr(0,4) + "-" + p.substr(4,4) : p ;  
       }  
       return _p8() + _p8(true) + _p8(true) + _p8();  
    }
```

Comment: sir no result i got ,same output